# How can we connect a Django app from local laptop to a SQL Managed instance that has azure AD authentication in place?

Tags: sql-server, django, azure

I am trying to connect a Django application from local laptop to Azure SQL Managed Instance with AD authentication in place.  I have the necessary permissions for the SQL as I have been configured to connect it from SSMS with same credentials.

I am trying to use ActiveDirectoryPassword as [mentioned here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-ver16). [django-pyodbc-azure 2.1.0.0
docs](https://pypi.org/project/django-pyodbc-azure/) and [microsoft/mssql-django docs](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django/wiki/Azure-AD-Authentication). [Microsoft docs to connect to Azure MI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/connect-application-instance?view=azuresql). My db settings in settings.py is as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'XXXX/db name',
        'USER': 'xxxx.xxxx@xxxx.com',
        'PASSWORD': 'XXXXXX',
        'HOST': 'tcp:XXX.public.XXXX.database.windows.net',
        'PORT': '3342',
        'OPTIONS': {'driver':'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
                    'extra_params': 'Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword',
                    },},}
```

Getting below error:

> django.db.utils.Error: ('FA004', "[FA004] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Failed to authenticate the user 'XXXX.XXXX@XXXXXXXX.com' in Active Directory (Authentication option is 'ActiveDirectoryPassword').\r\nError code 0xCAA2000C; state 10\r\nAADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access

Similar issue has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70694922/how-to-connect-to-azure-sql-server-using-managed-service-identity-from-django-ap).

Answer (score 0):

> AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access

This can be because your tenant's `Security Defaults` has been activated**. You may turn it off by going to

**Azure Portal >> Azure Active Directory >> Properties >> Select Manage Security Defaults >> Change the value of the Enable Security Defaults button to NO**.

Refer this [Microsofts official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults) for more information about Security Defaults

Comment: This worked for us after we removed the multi-factor authentication from the account.